# Send HTTP GET request to me every X minutes

Tags: api, http, windows-services

I have a job that needs to run every N minutes throughout the day. I have made a web service that starts this job whenever it receives an HTTP GET request. I have a windows server but don't feel like dealing with windows services, so I am wondering if there is a service of some kind that will fire an HTTP GET to my URL every N minutes?

Answer (score 3):

How about using a simple script/executable that is being run periodically from the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (there's a UI for it as well)?

For the thing to be scheduled there are many options, for example:

- use wget/[curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) to do the HTTP GET
- use Powershell to put some more logic inside (e.g. error reporting)
- roll out own executable if you really need something special

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an external service, such as www.setCronJob.com, that allows you to schedule url requests.  The advantage of these services too is that you can receive email alerts if the request fails.

Comment: Provided that the URL is reachable from the Internet?

Comment: Yes, clearly.  To make it a little less susceptible to random hits, you can add a long url key, e.g. key=23432kjlk343909j30rj3 and check for this server side before adding the job.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is create a scheduled task that runs [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that will work on all versions of Windows without installing anything additional, then just create a Windows Script file that you schedule to run via the task scheduler. You can use the following snippet of code in your Windows Script:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
If Err.Number = 0 Then

    objIE.Visible = false
    objIE.Navigate("http://localhost/Ping.asp")
    Do While objIE.Busy
        '
    Loop
    Set objIE = nothing
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

OR, even simpler, simply use "curl" in Task Scheduler.

curl "https://www.google.com"

This is by far the simplest and easiet.